# which of the spaces are Locally Compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**[NBHM_2006_PhD Screening Test_Topology]**

> which of the spaces are Locally Compact
>
> 1. $A=\{(x,y): x,y \text{ odd integers}\}$
> 2. $B=\{(x,y): x,y\text{ irrationals}\}$
> 3. $C=\{(x,y): 0\le x<1, 0<y\le 1\}$
> 4. $D=\{(x,y): x^2+103xy+7y^2>5\}$

A topological space $X$  is locally compact if every point has a neighborhood which is contained in a compact set.

well, I can prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally compact, so 1,2, are not Locally Compact, 3 is clearly locally compact. I am not ssure about 4. thank you.

Comment: 1. is locally compact, as it is discrete.

Comment: There is some information missing; $A$, $B$, and so on, are presumably subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$? We need a topology on a set to decide whether or not it is locally compact!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A subset of $\mathbf R^2$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded (by Heine-Borel theorem), so a subspace of $\mathbf R^2$ is locally compact iff a small enough closed ball around any given point is still closed as a subset of $\mathbf R^2$ (because compactness is absolute, and of course it is bounded).
This should be enough to solve the problem by yourself.

As for the answers, 1 is locally compact as martini said, 2 is indeed not locally compact (but it does not follow from the fact $\mathbf Q$ is not locally compact), 3 is locally compact, and 4. is locally compact.

As an additional hint for 4.: notice that it is an open subset of $\mathbf R^2$.

Comment: Ok : ) ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @tomasz Are you sure that 3 is compact? I think it is not even closed ( the bottom and right edges of the square are not included).

Comment: @BenjaLim: right, I missed the strict inequalities.

Comment: thank you all I have understood :)

Answer (score 5):

For 4):

All open or closed subsets of a locally compact Hausdorff space are locally compact in the subspace topology. $R^2$ is locally compact and Hausdorff and $D = p^{-1}((5, \infty))$ is the inverse image of an open set under a continuous function $p(x,y) = x^2+103xy+7y^2$.

Comment: Assuming the subspace topology.

Comment: One thing: Is  the subspace topology on $D$ the same as the (Euclidean) topology on $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @BenjaLim I'm not sure I understand your question. A set $\overline{O}$ in $D$ is open in the subspace topology if and only if there is an open set $O$ in $R^2$ such that $D \cap O = \overline{O}$.

Comment: So I guess one could say that they are the same.

Comment: thank you all I have understood :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe 4 is locally compact when you consider $\Bbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean topology. If you plot the region $D$ in [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20%2b%20103x%2ay%20%2b%207y%5E2%20%3E%205), you should see why.

By the way the fact that 2) is not locally compact *does not follow* from $\Bbb{Q}$ being not locally compact, although the proof is similar.

Comment: thank you all I have understood :)

Comment: @Patience The proof of $\Bbb{Q}$ being not locally compact that I'm referring to is not the one that uses the Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: sorry I really dont get your last comment.